# Copying alternative nodes from one single linked list to another in java

Tags: java, generics, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a method called copyAlternate which copy alternate elements from a single linked list and put them in another Single linked list sent as a parameter in the method

for example: if the first Single Linked List is( 4,6,10,12,2) 
the method should generate a single linked list with (4,10,2)

here is my code:

```
public boolean copyAlternate(SingleLinkedList<E> list1)
{

        if(head==null)
            return false;

        Node <E> temp = head;
        ArrayList <E> a1 = new ArrayList<E>();

        while(temp!=null) {
            a1.add(temp.data);
            temp=temp.next;
        }

        Node<E> tmp1=list1.head;
        for(int i=0;i<a1.size();i=i+2){

            if(list1.head==null) {
                list1.head =new Node(a1.get(i));
                tmp1=head;
                size++;
            }
            else
            {

             tmp1.next=new Node(a1.get(i));
             size++;
             tmp1=tmp1.next;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I got only 4 from method not (4,10,2) 
so what is the problem with my code?

Comment: It is difficult to correct the code without seeing both classes SingleLinkedList and Node. But one thing is for sure that you don't need another ArrayList, you can directly copy the alternative nodes from a list to another.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example if you need it, try not to copy it entirely but study it and understand what it's doing:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingleLinkedList<Integer> list = new SingleLinkedList<>();
        // (4, 6, 10, 12, 2)
        list.add(4).add(6).add(10).add(12).add(2);
        SingleLinkedList<Integer> newList = copyAlternate(list);
        System.out.println(newList);
        // prints: (14, 10, 2)
    }

    public static class Node<T> {
        public Node<T> next;
        public T data;

        public Node() {}
        public Node(T data) {this.data = data;}
    }

    public static class SingleLinkedList<T> {
        private Node<T> head;
        private Node<T> tail;

        public SingleLinkedList<T> add(T data) {
            if (tail != null) {
                tail.next = new Node<>(data);
                tail = tail.next;
            } else {
                head = new Node<>(data);
                tail = head;
            }
            return this;
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (head != null) {
                sb.append(head.data);
                Node<T> curr = head.next;
                while (curr != null) {
                    sb.append(", ").append(curr.data);
                    curr = curr.next;
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Copies only the even index nodes (0, 2, 4..) into a new list and returns that list. 
     * Doesn't create a deep copy of data
     */
    public static <T> SingleLinkedList<T> copyAlternate(SingleLinkedList<T> list) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(list, "list");
        SingleLinkedList<T> newList = new SingleLinkedList<>();
        Node<T> other = list.head;
        if (other != null) {
            // copy other data to head of new list and remember that as the current node
            Node<T> curr = newList.head = new Node<>(other.data);
            // get the next next other node
            other = other.next;
            if (other != null) {
                other = other.next;
            }
            while (other != null) {
                // copy the data into the next node then remember that as the current node
                curr = curr.next = new Node<>(other.data);
                // get the next next other node
                other = other.next;
                if (other != null) {
                    other = other.next;
                }
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can achieve it. Hope it will help.

```
// define the structure of a single node
class ListNode<T>
{
   public T data;

   public ListNode<T> next;

   public ListNode(T data)
   {
      this.data = data;
      this.next = null;
   }
}

public class SingleLinkedListGenerics<T>
{
   private ListNode<T> head = null;

   private ListNode<T> tail = null;

   // used to insert a node at the end of linked list
   public void insertLast(T data)
   {
      ListNode<T> newNode = new ListNode<>(data);

      if (head == null)
      {
         head = tail = newNode;
      }
      else
      {
         tail.next = newNode;
         tail = newNode;
      }
   }

   // For printing Linked List
   public void displayList()
   {
      System.out.println("\nPrinting LinkedList (head --> last) ");
      ListNode<T> current = head;
      while (current != null)
      {
         System.out.println(current.data + ", ");
         current = current.next;
      }
   }

   public static <T> SingleLinkedListGenerics<T> copyAlternate(SingleLinkedListGenerics<T> list)
   {

      if (list.head == null)
         return null;

      SingleLinkedListGenerics<T> newList = new SingleLinkedListGenerics<>();

      ListNode<T> tmp = list.head;

      ListNode<T> newNode = new ListNode<>(tmp.data); // getting the first node
      newList.head = newNode;
      newList.tail = newNode;

      tmp = tmp.next;

      while (tmp != null && tmp.next != null) //
      {
         tmp = tmp.next; // skipping one node

         newList.insertLast(tmp.data);

         tmp = tmp.next;
      }

      return newList;
   }


   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      SingleLinkedListGenerics<Integer> myLinkedlist = new SingleLinkedListGenerics<>();
      myLinkedlist.insertLast(4);
      myLinkedlist.insertLast(6);
      myLinkedlist.insertLast(10);
      myLinkedlist.insertLast(12);
      myLinkedlist.insertLast(2);

      myLinkedlist.displayList();

      SingleLinkedListGenerics<Integer> myLinkedlist1 = copyAlternate(myLinkedlist);

      myLinkedlist1.displayList();
   }
}
```